# How to copy artifacts from one repo to another repo

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

How to copy artifacts in artifactory from one repo to another repo using  Jenkins parameters declarative pipelines( any artifactoy rest api). Please advise.Thanks.

Comment: The Artifactory REST API you can use is https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CopyItem

Answer (score 0):

You can use promotion to copy all build artifacts from repository 'source-repo' to repository 'target-repo':

```
rtPromote (
   serverId: SERVER_ID,
   sourceRepo: 'source-repo',
   targetRepo: 'target-repo',
   copy: true // This will copy the artifacts instead of move them
)
```

For more information, here you can read the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-PromotingBuildsinArtifactory) and find the [full example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/promotion-example/Jenkinsfile).

**Interactive promotion**:

For late promotions (Not during the build) use interactive promotion. Here you can read the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-AllowingInteractivePromotionforPublishedBuilds) and find the [full example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/declarative-examples/interactive-promotion-example/Jenkinsfile).